# Saving entry to the Database

Tags: php, html, css

I have managed to make a connection to the database for a simple form that will store some entry. It does show that an entry has been submitted with the form however, it doesn't display the info that was submitted. Instead it has displays NULL in the Entry column that I created in the Table. I need it to display the submitted content. here's my code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'
    && $_POST['submit']=='Save Entry'
    && !empty($_POST['title'])
    && !empty($_POST['entry'])) 
{
    // Include database credentials and connect to the database
    include_once 'db.inc.php';
    $db = new PDO(DB_INFO, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

    // Save the entry into the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO entries (title, entry) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($title, $entry));
    $stmt->closeCusor();

    // Get the ID of the entry we just saved
    $id_obj = $db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID");
    $id = $id_obj->fetch();
    $id_obj->closeCursor();

    // Continue processing information
}

// If both conditions aren't met, sends the user back to the main page
else {
    header('Location: ../amin.php');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set values for `$title` and `$entry` anywhere. You also have a typo where you try to call call `closeCursor()`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting out the typo. I have fixed it... I set the values and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably register_globals is off (deprecated since PHP 5.3 for good reason). This means you have to read `$title` and `$entry` from the $_POST array:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$entry = $_POST['entry'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... This was really the difference. I'm still new in PHP and working my way through.